# Comment among a string of several lines in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, printf, comments

Let's say I have something like this in MATLAB:

```
fprintf(['some string\n'...
         'more string\n' ...
         'even some more\n'])
```

What I want to do is comment out the second line like this:

```
fprintf(['some string\n'...
        % 'more string\n' ...
         'even some more\n'])
```

But there is the following error when I do this:

```
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

I have a long line of strings, so I really need to be able to comment some of them out. What's the easiest and cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a `...` before the comment, or instead of the `%` sign:

```
fprintf(['some string\n'...
         ...  'more string\n' ...
         'even some more\n'])
```

or:

```
fprintf(['some string\n'...
         ... % 'more string\n' ...
         'even some more\n'])
```

Comment: That was a nice and smart solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give up the line:

```
fprintf(['some string\n'... % 'more string\n' ...
     'even some more\n'])
```

That is: comment and delete the new line.

Comment: So you think there is no way to keep the line there in its original place and comment it out?

Comment: @secluded AFAIK no.